# empty field show error for insert batch in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have multiple form field. I want to insert more than 25 row in db with insert_batch in codeigniter. like

```
 public function purchase(){

  $data = array(

  array(

         'date'=> $this->input->post('date'),
         'vendor_name'=>$this->input->post('vendor_name'),
         'model'=>$this->input->post('model'),
         'price' =>$this->input->post('price'), 
         'purchase_quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
         'amount'  =>$this->input->post('price')*$this->input->post('quantity'),
         'invoice_no'=>$this->input->post('invoice')
         ),

          array(
         'date'=> $this->input->post('date'),
         'vendor_name'=>$this->input->post('vendor_name2'),
         'model'=>$this->input->post('model2'),
         'price' =>$this->input->post('price2'), 
         'purchase_quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity2'),
         'amount'  =>$this->input->post('price2')*$this->input->post('quantity2'),
         'invoice_no'=>$this->input->post('invoice')
         ),

          array(
         'date'=> $this->input->post('date'),
         'vendor_name'=>$this->input->post('vendor_name3'),
         'model'=>$this->input->post('model3'),
         'price' =>$this->input->post('price3'), 
         'purchase_quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity3'),
         'amount'  =>$this->input->post('price3')*$this->input->post('quantity3'),
         'invoice_no'=>$this->input->post('invoice')
         )

         );

  $insert = $this->db->insert_batch('purchase',$data);

  return $insert; 

  }
```

but if I complete two field and submit it show error like

Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'purchase_quantity' at row 3

```
INSERT INTO `purchase` (`amount`, `date`, `invoice_no`, `model`, `price`, 

`purchase_quantity`, `vendor_name`) VALUES 

(4995,'18-09-2014','vvvvv','m6','999','5','mizan'), 

(5000,'18-09-2014','vvvvv','ab12','1000','5','abcde'), (0,'18-09-2014','vvvvv',0,0,'','')
```

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\final\sys\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Please help.

Comment: Just check with condition `($this->input->post('quantity3'))?$this->input->post('quantity3'):0`

Comment: try like this `'purchase_quantity'=>(int)$this->input->post('quantity3'),`

Comment: dear mr. Kumar_v3, error gone. thanks. but actually i want to insert those field which i fill up. and others want to ignore. But in db insert date and invoice and others 0. i want to ignore totally.

Comment: dear mr. Senk, error gone. thanks. but actually i want to insert those field which i fill up. and others want to ignore. But in db insert date and invoice and others 0. i want to ignore totally.

Answer (score 1):

use intval before integer values..

```
intval($this->input->post('quantity2'))
```

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/238144/

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use variables to insert batch data.

```
$purchase_quantity=empty($this->input->post('quantity3'))==true?0:$this->input->post('quantity3');
```

And use this `$purchase_quantity` in array to insert.

The code above will check if quantitiy3 have empty value (ie 0,null or false) it will replace with `0` (An integer) and save in variable that you can use in array to insert

Answer (score 0):

you can set the values as null or default value if form elements are empty like this..

```
'date'=>($this->input->post('date'))?$this->input->post('date'):null;
```

or

```
'date'=>($this->input->post('date'))?$this->input->post('date'):date('Y-m-d');
```

Or do like this if you want to ignore insert totally:

```
$data = array();
for($i=1;$i<=25;$i++)
{
    if($i>1)
    {
      if($this->input->post('vendor_name'.$i) && $this->input->post('model'.$i) && $this->input->post('price'.$i) && $this->input->post('quantity'.$i))
      {
        $record = array(
         'date'=> $this->input->post('date'),
         'vendor_name'=>$this->input->post('vendor_name'.$i),
         'model'=>$this->input->post('model'.$i),
         'price' =>$this->input->post('price'.$i), 
         'purchase_quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'.$i),
         'amount'  =>$this->input->post('price'.$i)*$this->input->post('quantity'.$i),
         'invoice_no'=>$this->input->post('invoice')
        );
        $data[]=$record;
      }
    }
    else{
       if($this->input->post('vendor_name') && $this->input->post('model') && $this->input->post('price') && $this->input->post('quantity'))
      {
         $record = array(
         'date'=> $this->input->post('date'),
         'vendor_name'=>$this->input->post('vendor_name'),
         'model'=>$this->input->post('model'),
         'price' =>$this->input->post('price'), 
         'purchase_quantity'=>$this->input->post('quantity'),
         'amount'  =>$this->input->post('price')*$this->input->post('quantity'),
         'invoice_no'=>$this->input->post('invoice')
        );
        $data[]=$record;
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: i got an error Column 'amount' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `purchase` (`amount`, `date`, `invoice_no`, `model`, `price`, `purchase_quantity`, `vendor_name`) VALUES (4995,'18-09-2014','tttttt','m6','999','5','mizan'), (4500,'18-09-2014','tttttt','cc32','900','5','mizan'), (NULL,'18-09-2014','tttttt',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)

Comment: you need to allow null value to column in table

Comment: put $data[]=$record; inside inner if in both conditions